# C: Is there a way to join together printed statements that use substitution?

Tags: printf, substitution

So here I'm printing numbers using substitution, and it would seem to me that there would be a way to join these three lines together without having to type `printf` 3 times.

```
printf("You can see here that 5 * 5 = %d\n", a);
printf("10/2 = %d\n", b);
printf("and the remainder of 10 divided by four is %d\n\n", c);
```

Another way to phrase this would be: Can I print these statements together without ending each one?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this printf("value1:%d\nvalue2:%d\nvalue3:%d\n", a, b, c);

Comment: oh, my bad...it's simpler than i thought it was